# Java loop gets stuck and doesnt exit

Tags: java, string, do-while

So im creating a game of blackjack as part of an assignment for my college. I have to create some kind of method to allow the player to Hit or Fold.I decided to write this part of code which checks the input:

```
do {
    System.out.println(playernames[j]+" (H/F)");
    playerinput=input.next();
} while (!((playerinput.equals("H"))||(playerinput.equals("F"))));
```

Everything runs smoothly until it reaches this loop.The workspace im working(eclipse) doesnt show any syntax problems nor any java exceptions occur.I tried editing this to find what is happening by using a temp boolean set to false before the loop and after the loop it gets set to true.The output didnt change meaning it didnt get past the loop.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(">" + playerinput + "<");` after the input asking, and tell us what is gives. because code works fine on its own

Answer (score 1):

This code works, but only if the user types a *capital* H or F. Maybe that's the problem? If you want to allow both lower case and upper case letters, you can use `playerinput.equalsIgnoreCase("H")`.

Also, `input.next()` will only return after the user has pressed enter. Just pressing the H or F key is not enough.

Comment: I specifically want capital H and F,but thats not my problem,the problem is that the code gets stuck in an infinite loop,I insert H or F and it still asks me without exiting the loop.